# Tableview frame issue when put in a scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I wanted to post a gif but apparently I don't have enough reputation. Oh well, whatever; I was using UIPageViewController, but for some reason I decided to go with a more manual solution by using UIScrollView and adding the views of UITableViewControlllers to the corresponding offsets (pages). I have 4 UItableViewControllers on each page (the views of table view controllers) and all of these are added to the container view controller (which has the UIScrollView) as child view controllers.

The actual problem is when I made the switch, table views began refusing  to go all the way down and part of the final table view cell stays trimmed by the end of the screen when the scrolling ends.

[image]

So, wanted to ask if anyone came across something like this before of know how to get rid of this. I know I could always use a library, but I want to learn. Here is some code:

```
_containerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
_containerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_containerScrollView.frame.size.width * 4, 0.0f);
_containerScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:_containerScrollView];

UITableViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITableViewController *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"trendingViewController"];
UITableViewController *vc3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"placesViewController"];
UITableViewController *vc4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"favoritesViewController"];

self.rallyViewControllers = [NSArray vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, nil];

[self addViewControllers];
```

Other methods;

```
- (void)addViewControllers{

     if (self.rallyViewControllers == nil) {

        return;

     }

     for (int i = 0; i < [self.rallyViewControllers count]; i++) {

         UIViewController* viewController = [self.rallyViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];

         [self addChildViewController:viewController];
         [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

         [_containerScrollView addSubview:viewController.view];

     }

}
```

This is called in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)configureFrames{

    if (self.rallyViewControllers == nil) {

    return;

    }

    CGFloat width = _containerScrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = _containerScrollView.frame.size.height;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.rallyViewControllers count]; i++) {

        UIViewController *viewController = [self.rallyViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(i * width, 0.0f, width, height);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The problem was when I added the view controllers views to the scroll view, they returned dimensions as if there was no navigation bar. But they were still positioned under the navigation bar, which caused total view to have 64 pt more height than the screen could show. when I manually subtracted 64 pt from views, and it was fixed. But since that is a very crude way of doing this, I then tried to fix it by fiddling with auto-layout, which ended up fine.

Answer (score 1):

I should state upfront that I didnt completely understand your description of

> "table views began refusing to go all the way down and part of the
>   final table view cell stays trimmed by the end of the screen when the
>   scrolling ends."

My answer is based on an issue I faced before. My setup is a uitableview in the storyboard container view ( without any parent scrollview)

I faced this issue where part of the tableview was cut off and I could not see about 5 bottom rows.

---

***Turns out I did not have any constraints setup between the parent container view and the tableview.***

---

To determine if your tableviews are rendering fine, get your project running in XCode and then press on the below button
[image: Visual stack of your views]

This button will then pause your app and give you a visual stack of the the different views that are currently rendered in your app. You can then see if any of the children ( in your case tableviews) are rendered outside the frame of the parent view in which case that portion will not be visible. This indicates that you either dont have constraints (or) the current constraints you have are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I already checked with the view hierarchy explorer or whatever it is called, but I couldn't see a problem in it. Question would be far cleare if i could post the damn gif. Can you elaborate the part about constraints? I am doing all of the stuff programmatically btw...

Comment: Refer here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1

Comment: I will do that. But it would also help me if you can show the constraints you put between those two. Just constraints to the 4 surrounding edges or did you also put fixed size constraints too? I know that constraints are a bit trickier when it comes to scroll views.

Comment: You will need to create constraints in such a way that every UI element knows exactly where it needs to render depending on the app orientation. The ideal place to start is to create constraints between each of tableview and the containing view and constraints between each tableviews. It is hard for me to comment about constraints without code on what you have currently

Comment: Ok, I will play with the constraints, it seems the problem is originating from that.

Comment: This was partly the issue but not the answer. Nevertheless, it was useful, so thanks.